# a reliable way to tell if = is for assignment in R code?

Tags: r

I'm a stubborn useR who uses `=` instead of `<-` all the time, and apparently many R programmers will frown on this. I wrote the [`formatR`](https://github.com/yihui/formatR/wiki) package which can replace `=` with `<-` based on the [`parser`](http://cran.r-project.org/package=parser) package. As some of you might know, `parser` was orphaned on CRAN a few days ago. Although it is back now, this made me hesitant to depend on it. I'm wondering if there is another way to safely replace `=` with `<-`, because not all `=`'s mean assignment, e.g. `fun(a = 1)`. Regular expressions are unlikely to be reliable (see [line 18](https://github.com/yihui/formatR/blob/master/R/utils.R#L18) of the `mask.inline()` function in `formatR`), but I will certainly appreciate it if you can improve mine. Perhaps the `codetools` package can help?

A few test cases:

```
# should replace
a = matrix(1, 1)
a = matrix(
  1, 1)

(a = 1)
a =
  1

function() {
  a = 1
}

# should not replace
c(
  a = 1
  )

c(
  a = c(
  1, 2))
```

Comment: Good and useful open-source code does not die and whither into disappearance---and parser now has a new maintainer as one would expect.  Where exactly is the problem in depending on a tested tool that does the job?

Comment: I certainly trust Andrew and the community won't let parser die. In fact I [wanted](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/211) to remove dependency on highlight/parser before they were orphaned; it is not worth the dependency for this relatively small feature (a long dependency chain has problems like maintenance and package loading time).

Comment: Why bother? And why is the question about replacing "=" with "<-" when your preference is for the former?

Comment: @mdsumner to satisfy other people who use `<-`... e.g. JSS won't accept `=` and I guess many people just die a little bit inside every time they see `=` for assignments in R

Comment: Be interesting to see if it's faster and easier to replace all single  instances of `=` with `<-` and then write a tool which figures out which `<-` have to be replace back with `=` for the scripts/functions to execute.

Comment: Right, seems strange since they have this usage in the guidelines: http://www.jstatsoft.org/style#q8

Comment: @Yihui It's right for JSS to require `<-` (though they need to clarify their style guidelines, as @mdsummer points out). `<-` and `=` [are not the same thing](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/assignOps.html), and in the interest of providing code examples that should "just work" everywhere, JSS is doing service to their readers with this policy.

Comment: @JasonMorgan I understand the decision of JSS but not from the pointview of "just work everywhere"; `=` works very well, as you can see in almost all other programming languages (R and S are weird to have their own `<-`). The only reason to use `<-` is just convention. It has no advantage over `=` (for some people, it does have visual advantages). Working everywhere can be dangerous (see [how experts can make mistakes](http://markmail.org/thread/tgt33474bkxz2hep)).

Comment: @Yihui As the link to the docs above make clear, `<-` and `=` are not the same thing: "The operator `<-` can be used anywhere, whereas the operator `=` is only allowed at the top level (e.g., in the complete expression typed at the command prompt) or as one of the subexpressions in a braced list of expressions." R and S may be "weird" in using `<-`, and it may be for historic reasons, but that's the language.

Comment: @JasonMorgan Yes, I understand they are different. I mean since `=` works well in other languages, there is no reason (except convention) for it to be a heretic in R. The historic reason was explained [here](http://developer.r-project.org/equalAssign.html), which is certainly not a strong reason nowadays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kohske sent a [pull request](https://github.com/kohske/formatR/commit/a2692d59f17ac9106e43f564857bc43d728fde6b) to the `formatR` package which solved the problem using the `codetools` package. The basic idea is to set a code walker to walk through the code; when it detects `=` as a symbol of a functional call, it is replaced by `<-`. This is due to the "Lisp nature" of R: `x = 1` is actually `` `=`(x, 1) `` (we replace it by `` `<-`(x, 1) ``); of course, `=` is treated differently in the parse tree of `fun(x = 1)`.

The `formatR` package (>= 0.5.2)  has since got rid of dependency on the `parser` package, and `replace.assign` should be robust now.

Comment: For what it is worth, I just heard that parts of parser may get incorporated into base R.

Answer (score 4):

This answer uses regular expressions.  There are a few edge cases where it will fail but it should be okay for most code.  If you need perfect matching then you'll need to use a parser, but the regexes can always be tweaked if you run into problems.

Watch out for

```
#quoted function names
`my cr*azily*named^function!`(x = 1:10)
#Nested brackets inside functions
mean(x = (3 + 1:10))
#assignments inside if or for blocks
if((x = 10) > 3) cat("foo")
#functions running over multiple lines will currently fail
#maybe fixable with paste(original_code, collapse = "\n")
mean(
  x = 1:10
)
```

The code is based upon an example on the `?regmatches` page.  The basic idea is: swap function contents for a placeholder, do the replacement, then put your function contents back.

```
#Sample code.  For real case, use 
#readLines("source_file.R")
original_code <- c("a = 1", "b = mean(x = 1)")

#Function contents are considered to be a function name, 
#an open bracket, some stuff, then a close bracket.
#Here function names are considered to be a letter or
#dot or underscore followed by optional letters, numbers, dots or 
#underscores.  This matches a few non-valid names (see ?match.names
#and warning above).
function_content <- gregexpr(
  "[[:alpha:]._][[:alnum:._]*\\([^)]*\\)", 
  original_code
)

#Take a copy of the code to modify
copy <- original_code

#Replace all instances of function contents with the word PLACEHOLDER.
#If you have that word inside your code already, things will break.
copy <- mapply(
  function(pattern, replacement, x) 
  {
    if(length(pattern) > 0) 
    {
      gsub(pattern, replacement, x, fixed = TRUE) 
    } else x
  }, 
  pattern = regmatches(copy, function_content), 
  replacement = "PLACEHOLDER", 
  x = copy,
  USE.NAMES = FALSE
)

#Replace = with <-
copy <- gsub("=", "<-", copy)

#Now substitute back your function contents
(fixed_code <- mapply(
  function(pattern, replacement, x) 
  {
      if(length(replacement) > 0) 
      {
          gsub(pattern, replacement, x, fixed = TRUE) 
      } else x
  }, 
  pattern = "PLACEHOLDER", 
  replacement = regmatches(original_code, function_content), 
  x = copy,
  USE.NAMES = FALSE
))

#Write back to your source file
#writeLines(fixed_code, "source_file_fixed.R")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate it. Kohske has come up with a brilliant solution with `codetools` and sent me a [pull request](https://github.com/kohske/formatR/commit/a2692d59f17ac9106e43f564857bc43d728fde6b) on Github. That is exactly the solution that I was looking for.

Comment: Wow.  Kohske's solution does look good.  And walking the code is bound to be more robust than a regex method.  Please relegate my answer to "a cute demo of regular expressions".

Answer (score -3):

The safest (and probably fastest) way to replace `=` by `<-` is directly typing `<-` instead of trying to replace it.

Comment: True, but if you have a zillion scripts that you need to "prettify", this could be of some help.

Comment: it's like saying grammar check programs are useless because you never make typos...

Comment: @flodel: typing '=' instead of '<-' is IMHO not a typo but something deliberate. It is more like not to conjugate verbs and purely rely on the grammar check programs to do it for you.